# podman machine - Cannot connect to Podman on MacOS

Tags: containers, podman

**Update: This is solved, please see the answer.**

I am using `podman` on MacOS with `podman machine` and now `podman` is unable to connect to the `podman machine`.

(It worked earlier but not sure the new macOS version causing the issue)

MacOS Monterey (12.1)

```
$ podman machine init
Extracting compressed file

$ podman machine start
INFO[0000] waiting for clients...                       
INFO[0000] listening tcp://127.0.0.1:7777               
INFO[0000] new connection from  to /var/folders/8f/v0tpqxg56wsf9x6x6tntjt5h0000gn/T/podman/qemu_podman-machine-default.sock 
Waiting for VM ...
Machine "podman-machine-default" started successfully

$ podman machine ls
NAME                     VM TYPE     CREATED             LAST UP            CPUS        MEMORY      DISK SIZE
podman-machine-default*  qemu        About a minute ago  Currently running  1           2.147GB     10.74GB

$ podman version
Cannot connect to Podman. Please verify your connection to the Linux system using `podman system connection list`, or try `podman machine init` and `podman machine start` to manage a new Linux VM
Error: unable to connect to Podman. failed to create sshClient: dial unix /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.WAh1QMSoLg/Listeners: connect: no such file or directory

$ podman ps
Cannot connect to Podman. Please verify your connection to the Linux system using `podman system connection list`, or try `podman machine init` and `podman machine start` to manage a new Linux VM
Error: unable to connect to Podman. failed to create sshClient: dial unix /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.WAh1QMSoLg/Listeners: connect: no such file or directory

$ podman run -dt -p 8080:80 nginx
Cannot connect to Podman. Please verify your connection to the Linux system using `podman system connection list`, or try `podman machine init` and `podman machine start` to manage a new Linux VM
Error: unable to connect to Podman. failed to create sshClient: dial unix /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.WAh1QMSoLg/Listeners: connect: no such file or directory

$ podman --log-level=debug version
INFO[0000] podman filtering at log level debug          
DEBU[0000] Called version.PersistentPreRunE(podman --log-level=debug version) 
DEBU[0000] SSH Ident Key "/Users/gini/.ssh/podman-machine-default" SHA256:duxS/j3bzl90jSUtbXVIofL4O+FqZ5sUL63c26u2gdo ssh-ed25519 
DEBU[0000] Found SSH_AUTH_SOCK "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.WAh1QMSoLg/Listeners", ssh-agent signer(s) enabled 
Cannot connect to Podman. Please verify your connection to the Linux system using `podman system connection list`, or try `podman machine init` and `podman machine start` to manage a new Linux VM
Error: unable to connect to Podman. failed to create sshClient: dial unix /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.WAh1QMSoLg/Listeners: connect: no such file or directory
```

**Describe the results you expected:**

Expecting to get the podman version and other information.

**Package info:**

```
$ brew info podman
podman: stable 3.4.4 (bottled), HEAD
Tool for managing OCI containers and pods
https://podman.io/
/usr/local/Cellar/podman/3.4.4 (170 files, 40MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-12-29 at 21:51:28
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/podman.rb
License: Apache-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: go ✘, go-md2man ✘
Required: qemu ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
zsh completions have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Analytics
install: 11,107 (30 days), 38,817 (90 days), 78,249 (365 days)
install-on-request: 11,111 (30 days), 38,825 (90 days), 78,240 (365 days)
build-error: 2 (30 days)
```

```
$ sw_vers 
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.1
BuildVersion:   21C52
```

Comment: @jmort253, 
thanks, I have checked that but the issue was with `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`
I have run `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and it is resolved.

Comment: podman released 4.x, possible to upgrade the version and update the questions? this part could be changed

Comment: it may popup some network permission issue  which u skipped

Comment: oh okay. I did not test since the workaround (below) was working. Thanks for sharing, will test it again. 
(I did not see any popup window though)

Comment: I've podman version 4.1.1, still having issue with that. unsetting SSH_AUTH_SOCK didn't work. It was working fine for couple of days and now I'm unable to start podman at all as it says `Error: dial unix /var/folders/ps/29ntn8ss037052ytz9s1jl_0v496q_/T/podman/connectionname_ready.sock: connect: connection refused`.

Comment: I was starting the podman machine with 16GB memory. after following the [discussion](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/14303) here, I used the default memory allocation (without any `-m` switch) and the machine started without showing any error.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to [Luap99](https://github.com/Luap99).

podman was trying to connect to the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` address but this is failing.

executed below command and the problem solved.

```
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Comment: or `set -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK` on fish (cf. https://stackoom.com/en/question/24pTY)

Comment: This worked, but I had to do a `podman machine stop` and `podman machine start` for it to take effect.

Answer (score 12):

I have this problem
I solve with this

After this all run correct

```
mkdir -p /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugin

podman machine stop
podman machine rm -f
podman machine init --now
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this worked?  Why does Podman need this empty directory?

Comment: Hi man, I use Docker now to with Colima as well! Podman don’t create this folder in my machine!

Answer (score 6):

Building upon Gineesh's answer, I also needed to set a default connection.

```
podman machine stop
podman system connection default podman-machine-default    
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
podman machine start
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsetting the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` might work if there is one set. For me it did not apply. I also removed and initiated a machine a few times, alas no success.
I set the machine to run rootful and that did the trick for me

```
podman machine set --rootful
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue got introduced via qemu library in order to fix this uninstall podman from brew and install via pkg file.

https://github.com/containers/podman/releases

Depending upon your chip set choose arm/amd release.